# Tuckey URLRewriteFilter alternative

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am looking to use the UrlRewriteFilter based on a recommendation.  It was working fine, until I tried to pass the parameters from the "From" to the "to".  I ended up getting "&" as the character between the URL and the parameters instead of the "?".  In researching this, it has been fixed since 2015, but the release 4.0.5 has never been made public in the maven repository.  4.0.4 is the latest and it is from 2012.  It looks like a great project, but does not appear to be maintained anymore.   Does anyone have an alternate project that they can recommend that is comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Tomcat 8.0 or later**, you can use `RewriteValve` to rewrite URLs.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html